# Visual Studio 10 DataGridView and DatePicker on Where clause

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, dataset, visual-foxpro

I am loading a visual fox pro database table into a data grid view in visual studio.  On the form there is also a date picker and I need to add what date is currently selected in my dataset query.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my current query:
SELECT     item.itemnumber, stdetail.stid, stdetail.qty, stdetail.recadded
FROM         item, stdetail
WHERE     item.itemid = stdetail.itemid

and im guessing I will add something like:

AND DatePick.Value = stdetail.recadded ????????

My second question is:
In the database dates are stored as 
2012-05-20 11:29:37

how do I compare just the date and leave the time off?  I'm trying to pick a date and see everything that sold that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare only the date, you can use the TTOD() function, which converts a datetime value to a date value:

AND TTOD(stDetail.RecAdded) =

Tamar